# Forum Page Subjects Show Up With Gaps

Tags: php, html

http://www.hisseforex.com/forum/

Above link is for my forum page. It used to be normal and working but I found it showing up subject lines with a gap suddenly. I tried to upload it again to my host yet it did not work. Can I get a little help with its cause and how to solve it?

Comment: It appears you have added some padding or margin spacing to an element. Did you change your CSS file or add any inline styling to your HTML? You most likely added margin/padding or a height/min-height CSS value OR you removed something that stopped the extra space.

Comment: Well I never changed my CSS file in that php. It was a default theme and did not change it.

Comment: Your question is too broad, you need to try and identify the problem.

Comment: Well either your CSS changed or this issue always existed and you didn't notice or due to browser dimensions and screen size. OR you added a bunch of spacing to a value on the DB and you didn't use trim() when inserting values. But without you supplying more info, I would be surprised if it's anything but one of those possible issues

Comment: I really dont know about the details but I finally decided to change my style since nothing helped me out of it. Thanks though. I will try to find that style on web and will download the original file again.

Answer (score 0):

Changed my style since I could not find any better option. Thanks everyone.